# How can i see execute command in Entity FrameWork?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, entity-framework

i try to use erpCtx.Executecommand but i doesn't have method of executecommand. i think that i must add dll in Reference to show executeCommand?

[image]

i need :  **int rowsAffected = engCtx.ExecuteCommand("insert into xtable Values({0},{1},{2},{3})", engArray[0], engArray[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwHwB.jpg), engArray[2], engArray[3]);**

Comment: What class is `ErpEntities` derived from?

Comment: ErpEntities is DataContext you can see it from Erp.Dal

Answer (score 2):

In the Entity Framework, it's called [ExecuteStoreCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 using (var db = new DAL.CrawlerDalEntities())
        {
            db.Connection.Open();
            using (var cmd = db.Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = storedProcedureDefaultTimeout;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "CrawlerDalEntities.PerformBackup";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new EntityParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "fileName",
                    Value = fileName,
                    DbType = DbType.String
                });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new EntityParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "backupName",
                    Value = backupName,
                    DbType = DbType.String
                });

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            db.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks But i need:   int rowsAffected = engCtx.ExecuteCommand("insert into ENG_MAINWP Values({0},{1},{2},{3})", engArray[0], engArray[1], engArray[2], engArray[3]);

Answer (score 0):

`DataContext.ExecuteCommand` is in:

> **Namespace:**  System.Data.Linq
>   **Assembly:**  System.Data.Linq (in System.Data.Linq.dll)

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx)

Comment: i add it but result the same as before. LOOK please:  http://i34.tinypic.com/1z1wq51.jpg

Comment: @Phsika - in that case I don't know. Do a clean and rebuild?